# In assemby , Is there something wrong with my function trying to return a value?

Tags: assembly

In assembly, the 'pop' command is used for returning a value specified right? I can't seem to make it work properly though. I try to print the input to see if the input was changed but the program instead loops twice before waiting for user input again.

The data declaration:

```
 section .data
  test db "Test",10
  testLen equ $-test
```

Here's the input declaration

```
section .bss
 input resb 1
```

Then the subprogram call:

```
section .text
 global _start

 _start:

 sub esp,2    ;this is for the return value
 call function    ; call the subprogram
 pop word[input]

 mov eax,4
 mov ebx,1
 mov ecx,input
 mov edx,1 ;1 character input only from user is expected
 int 80h

 mov eax,4
 mov ebx,1
 mov ecx,test
 mov edx,testLen
 int 80h

 jmp _start
```

Then the subprogram :

```
function:
 mov eax,3
 mov ebx,0
 mov ecx,[esp+4]
 mov edx,2 ;of length 2 because only 1 character is expected from user + the \n char 
 int 80h

 ret
```

Am I doing something wrong with my scanning routine in the subprogram 'function'? Thank you for those who would help me out. Just beginning to learn subprograms in Assembly and I couldn't figure this one out. Been stuck in this simple bug for an hour now.

Comment: In general `pop` is not used for returning, `mov eax, SOMETHING` is. But this looks like hand-written asm that doesn't follow any standard calling convention.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, let me see if I'm guessing where you are misunderstanding and help you clear it up.

You have heard a phrase bantered around by know-it-alls and it goes something like this "*The stack is used to pass variables between functions*." Yes this is true; but incompletely true, and it has confused the living daylights out of you.

I'm also assuming that you are thinking in the context of C and assembly.

Okay now, with respect to C, a function has a "type", as I'm guessing you are aware.

With respect to assembly language, a function has no type.

(We'll stick with x86 here, although it generally holds true for a bunch of others)

For assembly language, you have the **Call** instruction, and the **Ret** instruction, and that's about it.

Oh, yes, you have the **Int** instruction on the x86, and some other similar chips as well; but for this moment, we'll just keep the focus on **Call** and **Ret**.

So anyway, this biz of "*passing parameters on the stack*" is (in C at least) approximately always set up so that

- Parameters are passed **TO** the function on the stack
- Values are returned **FROM** the function in a register

I think that's where your confusion is.

I can see that you are earnest in your desire to learn assembly, and that you are, well, "creative" in the use of the stack for passing variables.

Who knows ? Maybe you've noticed a better way (but I seriously doubt it; use registers for what you're trying to do)

Anyway, if I'm guessing properly, you never write anything into that space in the stack that you created for the `function` to fill

Here's what you do to confirm or deny this.

Debug this by Single stepping it with a breakpoint at each of these three instructions...

```
  sub    esp,2        ;this is for the return value
  call   function     ; call the subprogram
  pop    word[input]
```

Open a watch window and observe the memory location of [Esp] before and after the `call function` instruction.

I think you'll find that you never wrote anything into that location.

Then again, while the concept might work in this case, it is generally a not-so-nice idea to try; so save yourself a lot of headaches and return a value in a register.

That's how compilers do it; and just ask the new experts: compilers are smarter than humans (but I digress)

Not sure if this helps, but I tried.

Answer (score 0):

Return values are usually returned in `eax` and only arguments and local variables are stored in the stack but this varies between calling conventions.

For example in cdecl calling convention that is used in C works like this:

```c
int callee(int, int, int);

int caller(void)
{
    int ret;
    ret = callee(1, 2, 3);
    ret += 5;
    return ret;
}
```

Translates to:

```
caller:
    push    ebp      ; store previous stack frame
    mov     ebp, esp ; set current stack frame (could be used to access local variables and arguments)
    push    3        ; push arguments to stack from right to left
    push    2
    push    1
    call    callee   ; eax contains return value of callee after this line
    add     esp, 12  ; clean stack from arguments passed to callee
    add     eax, 5   ; add 5 return value of callee
    pop     ebp      ; restore previous stack frame
    ret              ; return value in eax
```

Wikipedia has great article about different calling conventions (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions).